# Making web crawler download multiple web pages locally

Tags: java, web-crawler

I would like my web crawler to download all the browsed URL's locally. At the minute it will download every site it comes to but then overwrite the local file in each website visited. The crawler start at www.bbc.co.uk, downloads that file and then when it hits another it overwrites that file with the next URL. How can I make it download them in to single files so I have a collection at the end? I have this code below but I dont know where to go from here. Any advice would be great. The URL inside the brackets (URL) is a string which is used to manipulate all the browsed webpages.

```
         URL url = new URL(URL);
             BufferedWriter writer;
                 try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
                            writer = new BufferedWriter
                          (new FileWriter("c:/temp/data.html", true));
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                //System.out.println(line);
                            writer.write(line);
                            writer.newLine();
                            }        
                        }
                             writer.close();
```

Comment: Give the files an unique name like: `"c:/temp/data"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".html"`

Comment: Will this mean that all of the downloaded files will be saved with just the value of the current time? All I need is a collection of whatever web pages it hits, they save individually. Thought I was so close but just so far away haha :)

Comment: This worked a treat!!! Is there any way to mark your answer as correct? Haven't really used stakeoverflow much. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad to hear it woks, is not necessary to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you can use any unique value. I've posted my solution as a comment, you can't accept it as the answer. @DavideLorenzoMARINO answer has the same idea, you can accept it instead.

Comment: I was trying to add my String URL as the name of the file but it gave this error.. Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\temp\http:\www.bbc.co.uk.html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Is it because that the http:\ thinks that its a new folder?

Comment: Yes, also `:` is not a valid filename character on windows, and there are a couple more characters you can't use in a folder/filename.

Comment: Yeah i knew that bit ;) haha but will try to manipulate it a bit further. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: Is there any way of using the URL of the web page as the name?

Comment: You can do something like this `URL.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")`, this will replace all non-alphanumeric characters with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give to your files a unique name.

You can save them in different folders (one root directory for each web site).

Or you can give them a unique name (using a counter for example).